# Improve performance when Searching SQL by Large Data Type?

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, search, large-data

**SCENARIO:**

I'm using a fingerprint identification system on .Net. Each fingerprint template is captured as bytes array type with a length of 1632, but most of them doesn't use all of the length. I insert them to SQL database as VARBINARY data type "Template" column.

Now to perform authentication, I need to compare my input fingerprint sample with the "Template" column (which is VARBINARY data type) in each SQL records.

**PROBLEM:**

I know that there will be a performance issue, as the "Template" column contains a large data type. My question is: what is the best way to search for a matching record based on a large VARBINARY data type column in my scenario? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea - fast search only use 16 bytes (stored computed column), use the index

[MSDN HashBytes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx)

[MSDN Computed persisted column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE [Fingerprint] (
    [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Fingerprint PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
--  ,[UserID] int NOT NULL
    ,[FingerprintBin]  VARBINARY(1632) NULL
    ,[SearchCriteria] as CAST(HASHBYTES('MD5',[FingerprintBin]) as BINARY(16)) PERSISTED
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Fingerprint_SearchCriteria] ON [Fingerprint] ([SearchCriteria]);
GO
```

Test data

```
INSERT INTO [Fingerprint] ([FingerprintBin])
    VALUES (0x010203040506)
GO
-- Insert 1000 random value
INSERT INTO [Fingerprint] ([FingerprintBin])
    VALUES (NEWID())
GO 1000
```

Fast search

```
DECLARE @FingerprintBin  VARBINARY(1632) = 0x010203040506

-- Index seek in execution plan
SELECT [ID]
FROM [Fingerprint]
WHERE [SearchCriteria] = CAST(HASHBYTES('MD5',@FingerprintBin) as BINARY(16))
    AND [FingerprintBin] = @FingerprintBin;
GO
```